# Can "mi" be used as a regular pronoun?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

*Mi* is usually used like this:

> **Esta es mi casa.** --> *This is my house.*

However, sometimes I've seen it used as a regular pronoun like this:

> **Él tiene más libros que mi.** --> He has more books than I.

Can *mi* also be used as a pronoun or should *yo* be used when referring to oneself as a pronoun in instances like this?

Comment: Your second use is not-grammatical, but "El libro es para mí" is correct. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "regular" pronoun--what makes one pronoun more or less regular than another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's wrong. It should say

> "Él tiene más libros que **yo**".

You can use "mi" as pronombre posesivo, as your first example, but to use it as a pronombre personal it needs the accent.

> "Mi amigo se alegra por mí".

First one is posesivo (my friend / el amigo mio). The second stands for the person who is talking (me / yo).

or

> Cuando digo mi nombre me refiero a mí mismo.

Please, notice that *mi* is **NOT** *mí*. That may be part of the confusion with the usage of this word.

Comment: You're right! I thought "mi" and "mí" were the same word but with different uses. It's all clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know where you have seen someone use 'mi' as a noun, but, as a native Spanish speaker, I can say that they're wrong using it that way.
'Mi' is the possessive pronoun. To expand on what Diego Alonso said, 'mí' is a personal pronoun. 
As a general tip, translate it to English and see if it makes sense.

```
He has more books than *my*.
```

It makes as much sense in English as it does in Spanish.

Comment: I think is lika a false cognade from someone who speaks english and confuses _me_ with _mi_ but not _my_.

Answer (score 2):

*Mi* is an *adjetivo posesivo* (like tu, su, nuestro, etc.)

*Mí*, notice the [diacritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic), is a [pronombre personal preposicional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronombres_en_espa%C3%B1ol). For example:

> Esta carta es para mí. *This letter has been sent to me.*

However, *yo* is also a *pronombre personal*, but it is a *pronombre personal no preposicional*. For example:

> Creo que yo puedo hacerlo. *I think I can do it.*

Your second example (*Él tiene más libros que mi.*) is a common mistake in some Spanish-native speakers (I have noticed it on Peruvian people). As Diego has answered, the correct sentence is *Él tiene más libros que **yo***.

It would be valid if you add something like:

> Él tiene más libros que mi hermano. *He has more books than my brother.*

However, in this case, *mi* is an *adjetivo posesivo*.

Comment: I think that _Él tiene más libros que mi_ is not a common mistake in Spanish speakers. Maybe in bilingual people from the US or from the Caribbean islands, but I don't think this could be common in native speakers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have heard it on people from the mountain side of Peru.

Comment: Kookoriko Could be that people speakers of another language, people who speaks a native american language as motehrtongue and Spanish as the second one and not alwyas correct, as happens in Mexico also.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you may be hearing is in phrases where an object comes after *que*:

> Le gustará más a ella que a mí.

In this case, you do need *mí* because it's *to me*.  No doubt this is probably what you heard, but because in English we've had a tendency to shift *than* to a prepositional status making *me* most common whether as subject or object in such constructions, your mind is probably trying to over generalize the use of *mí* to places where you need a subject pronoun.